# scheduling a Thread after a Thread in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsthread

I want to schedule a thread after a thread completion.

Is it possible ? How?

For example ( to specify my need )

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // 1. response - schedule myThread 
    // 2. response - schedule a new thread which will be executed after myThread
    // 3. response - schedule a new thread which will be executed after second thread
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Dare I ask why these all need to be separate threads, if they're executing a set of strictly serial tasks?

Comment: Do you have fill example represent this case , i need it now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use [NSOperations](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) you can use the [addDependency:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW2) method to specify an operation's dependencies.

[NSInvocationOperation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocationOperation) will probably be useful to you if you go this route.

Edit: I just re-read the subject and you're on iPhone so you don't have blocks, but for reference, if you have blocks available, [NSBlockOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBlockOperation) is even better.

Note that when using these methods to perform asynchronous operations (and assuming the code in them uses autorelease) you'll be responsible for instantiating an `NSAutoreleasePool` when your method starts running and releasing/draining it upon exit.

Comment: Blocks, and hence NSBlockOperation are not available on iPhone (yet). (Also, your links point to the Mac OS X documentation; since this was an iPhone question, the iPhone OS documentation would be more appropriate.)

Comment: **Update:** As of iOS 4.0 we now have blocks.

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can poll the threads `isFinished` property.

(2) You can register your dispatching/controlling object to receive the threads `NSThreadWillExitNotification` notification. For more precise control, you can subclass NSThread and to send a notification as the last act before the thread stops. Then in your controlling objects notification handler you can poll `isFinished` to make sure its done before launching the next thread.

See [Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [NSThread Class Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CJBGIAIF).